# Add "Starting from" in front of prices on category page in open cart store

Tags: php, task-parallel-library, opencart

I'm trying to edit the template and I need to add "Starting from" in front of the prices on the catalog page (and then maybe the product page, but one step at a time)

I've located where it echos the price in the tpl file

```
<p class="price">
<?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
<?php echo $product['price']; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

What I tried was to add a row in the oc_product table called starting_from and manually enter "Starting from" in each one. (there are only 6 products for now).

With very little knowlegde i added

```
<?php echo $product['starting_from']; ?>
```

so it then looked like this

```
 <p class="price">
<?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
<?php echo $product['starting_from']; ?>
<?php echo $product['price']; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Shockingly, it didn't work.

Can someone try and explain the magnitude of my errors, please?
And maybe help me out.

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your want to simply add the hardcoded string *Starting from*, you can do:

```
<p class="price">Starting from
<?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
<?php echo $product['price']; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
<span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span> <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Actually, if I got you right, this is very basic, so I'd recommend some PHP tutorial to start with.